# Strange error when adding items to prototype cells in storyboard-IB

Tags: ios, uitableview, iboutlet

I have quite a large project (~20 scenes). One of which is a TableViewController with a custom UITableViewController class. I have given the cell a reuse identifier, and added a label to it. When I try and Ctrl+Drag the label to the UITableViewController header file to create an outlet, I get the following error:

> error: Illegal Configuration: Connection "tableInfoView" cannot have a
>   prototype object as its destination.

What is this? Am I overlooking something obvious? Or do I need to create a custom cell class and drag the outlet to that? If so, how do I then specify the data which is displayed uniquely for each cell from the UITableViewController?

Comment: You can't connect the prototype's label to an outlet in the table view controller, since the controller is not the prototype's owner (`UITableViewCell` is). For prototypes of dynamic cells, you need to do something like set a tag on the cell and look the label up using that after you dequeue the cell.

Comment: Just figured that out :P Thanks for your help anyway! Write it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

In fact you can't just make an outlet from a dynamic cell prototype in the `UITableView` delegate view controller.

You'll have to subclass `UITableViewCell` and then attribute this class to your prototype.

Then you can Ctrl-Drag from the Label to the `UITableViewCell` subclass header file.

Finaly you can access to this outlet in the delegate code after having imported the `UITableViewCell` header file in it.

This is documented by Apple [there](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW1) at "The Technique for Dynamic Row Content" section.

Comment: What do you mean by "grouped cells" ?

Answer (score 10):

or you could give the label a tag (e.g. 100) and use

```
myLabel = [myTableView viewForTag:100];
```

to get the label

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error myself. Just to add one more potantial root cause for future readers:

In my case I copied a control (a Button in this case) from one prototype cell to the next and the action still referred to the neighbor cell. My table has several different prototype cells.

The fact, that it acutally was a proper subclass of UITableViewCell which was properly connected to the prototype cell made it difficult to actually see the mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Tag the label and you can reach the label anywhere in the viewcontroller like with viewWithTag from the table view.

```
    UILabel *destinationLabel = (UILabel *)[self.tableView viewWithTag:1];


    destinationLabel.text = @"Label Destaination";
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem but later it turned out that it was just a silly mistake.
**I mistakenly dragged the label from Cell to my controller's `@interface`**

This could be your problem too. just cross check once.

Comment: I don't think the poster is asking for an IBAction but rather an outlet to configure the control.

Comment: @LeviRoberts I am not talking about IBActions here.

Answer (score -1):

Set the right reuse identifier used in .m file in the Storyboard for the Prototype cell.I had the same situation and this helped me

Answer (score -2):

After doing every thing right if problem still exist then just removed all outlets and rejoin them carefully and it worked very fine for me.