# Issue with creating IBOutlet in storyboard

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

I have created a UICollectionViewController custom class , and I inserted an UIImageView into the cell , then created an IBOutlet :

```
@property (weak , nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageCell;
```

[image]

but when I compile the project , debugger gives me this error :

[image]

Thanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a custom class - the child of UIImageView. Something like MyCustomImageView and set it to the outlet's class. And one more thing - you should better create an outlets with `strong` modifier. Also take a look at the link provided in comment to your question [more information on your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12150715/strange-error-when-adding-items-to-prototype-cells-in-storyboard-ib)