# How to always stick button and label together

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, uilabel

I want to have a button and label who always stick together. I want it to be static and I found a solution which uses the UICollectionView with cells. I got the `"Connection "" cannot have a prototype object as its destination"` and found a solution here: [Strange error when adding items to prototype cells in storyboard-IB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12150715/strange-error-when-adding-items-to-prototype-cells-in-storyboard-ib) but the answer given there is talking about a dynamic one. What is the right way to do this? I don't need to have a @property from the cell, I only need to have a @property from the button and label and I just want the label and button to stick together. So actually something like this:

[image]

Comment: You can Wrap them under a Box, change the box proerties as no title no border etc.

Comment: What do you mean by "box"?

Comment: How about `UITableView`? I suggest you read this. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html

Comment: you can put them into a view. sorry I was thinking ios also has box as in osx.

Comment: @Desdenova, yes a table view would do but the problem remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

You should make a `UIView` with a `UIButton` and a `UILabel` as its subviews.
If you want to use `UITableView` or `UICollectionView`, this parent `UIView` will actually be the `UITableViewCell` or `UICollectionViewCell`.